# Задача "Игра - 2" валится на 12 тесте

Tags: c++, олимпиада

(Время: 1 сек. Память: 16 Мб Сложность: 45%)
Вы любите играть в игры? Конечно, любите! Но про эту игру, возможно, ничего не знаете и не слышали даже. Что ж, расскажем о новой игре. На доске написана последовательность n целых чисел. Играют двое. На очередном ходе игрок выбирает число с правого или с левого края последовательности, затем это число стирается и последовательность становится на одно число меньше, а ход переходит к противнику. Выигрывает тот, кто наберет в сумме больше. Написать программу, определяющую победителя в конкретной игре, при условии, что игроки будут играть оптимально.

Входные данные

В первой строке входного файла INPUT.TXT записано целое число n (0 < n < 100). Во второй строке через пробел заданы n натуральных чисел, не превосходящих 1000.

Выходные данные

В единственную строку выходного файла OUTPUT.TXT нужно вывести 1, если победит первый игрок, 2 – если победит второй игрок и 0 – в случае ничьей.
Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

bool fmax(int a, int b){
    return a > b;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> mas;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int num;
        cin >> num;
        mas.push_back(num);
    }
    int flag = 0;
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if (mas.size() < 4){
            if (flag == 0) {
                if (mas[0] > mas[mas.size() - 1]) {
                    x += mas[0];
                    mas.erase(mas.begin() + 0);
                }
                else{
                    x += mas[mas.size() - 1];
                    mas.pop_back();
                }
            }
            else {
                if (mas[0] > mas[mas.size() - 1]) {
                    y += mas[0];
                    mas.erase(mas.begin() + 0);
                }
                else{
                    y += mas[mas.size() - 1];
                    mas.pop_back();
                }
            }
            flag = (flag + 1) % 2;
        }
        else {
            int a = mas[0] + mas[mas.size() - 2];
            int b = mas[mas.size() - 1] + mas[1];
            if (flag == 0) {
                if (b != a) {
                    if (b > a) {
                        x += mas[mas.size() - 1];
                        mas.pop_back();
                    } else {
                        x += mas[0];
                        mas.erase(mas.begin() + 0);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    if (fmax(mas[0], mas[mas.size() - 1])){
                        x += mas[0];
                        mas.erase(mas.begin() + 0);
                    }
                    else{
                        x += mas[mas.size() - 1];
                        mas.pop_back();
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                if (b != a) {
                    if (b > a) {
                        y += mas[mas.size() - 1];
                        mas.pop_back();
                    } else {
                        y += mas[0];
                        mas.erase(mas.begin() + 0);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (fmax(mas[0], mas[mas.size() - 1])){
                        y += mas[0];
                        mas.erase(mas.begin() + 0);
                    }
                    else{
                        y += mas[mas.size() - 1];
                        mas.pop_back();
                    }
                }
            }
            flag = (flag + 1) % 2;
        }
    }
    if (x > y)
        cout << 1;
    else if (x < y)
        cout << 2;
    else
        cout << 0;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Для начала - опишите алгоритм, который Вы пробуете использовать для поиска решения. Может он тупо ошибочен?

Comment: ссылка на сайт с задачей: https://acmp.ru/asp/do/index.asp?main=task&id_course=2&id_section=15&id_topic=16&id_problem=88

Comment: Я сравниваю сумму 1 и предпоследнего элемента с суммой последнего и 2 элемента. Потом убираю элемент с края сумма с которым больше. Если суммы одинаковы то беру тот который больше с края. А если размер массива меньше 4 то я беру тот элемент с края который больше.

Comment: Во-первых - это должно быть в тексте вопроса, а не в комментарии. Во-вторых, я не вижу даже оснований считать, что этот алгоритм оптимален **для обеих сторон**, не говоря уж о доказательстве этого факта. И, если Вы нигде не напахали в реализации алгоритма, то "завал на 12 тесте" - прекрасное основание считать алгоритм несостоятельным.

Comment: Насчет первого понял, а на насчет второго не понял.

Comment: *насчет второго не понял* Для опровержения теории достаточно одного контрпримера. Раз тест номер 12 является контрпримером, то ваша теория о правильности описанного алгоритма ошибочна.

Comment: Я уверен что проблема заключается в недоработке алгоритма, а не в том что этот алгоритм полностью неверен. И прошу подсказать что в нем не так.

Comment: Алгоритм или верен, или ошибочен. Это как "нельзя быть немножко беременной". Насчёт доработки - возможно, и поможет... хотя мне кажется, что Вы неправильно его формируете - начинаете с начала и с конца, а он, скорее всего, не стыкуется в середине. Для трёх элементов - не спорю, верно. Теперь на его базе постройте для четырёх. Потом для пяти. И так, пока не дойдёте до состояния, когда дальше можно будет продолжить рекуррентно.

Comment: Вот вам доп чтоб подумать  14, 1, 45, 14 какой возмете в данной ситуации? Кто откроет 45 тот ипроиграл

Comment: Как раз таки этот тест проходит. Первый берет число слева, второй берет число справа, первый берет число справа и выигрывает.

Comment: Типичное ДП. Кстати, вот полный анализ: [1](https://pro-prof.com/forums/topic/acmp_38), [2](https://plusplusmustlive.blogspot.com/2019/12/38-2.html), [3](https://www.cyberforum.ru/algorithms/thread59511.html)... После этого писать свой ответ как-то уже и не комильфо :)

Comment: То есть моим алгоритмом решить задачу нельзя?